# Understanding open balls in the Euclidean topology are Zariski dense. Why is $V(I(B))$ the closure?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

To prove this, take any open ball $B=B(z,\epsilon)$ in the Euclidean topology, then the set of polynomials vanishing on $B$ is $I(B)=\{0\}$, and the associated algebraic variety is $V(I(B))=\mathbb{A}^n.$ It is then said that this prove $B$ is dense in the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{A}^n$.

I don't understand the final implication. How exactly does $V(I(B))=\mathbb{A}^n$ prove that $B$ is dense?

Edit: If $V(I(B))$ is supposed to be the closure of $B$, then I'm not seeing how do we know this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be a closed set containing $V(I(B))$. By definition of the Zariski topology, there is an ideal $J$ of polynomials on $\mathbb{A}^n$ such that $C = V(J)$.

For any $f \in J$, $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in C$, and in particular, for all $x \in B$, so $f \in I(B)$ the ideal of all polynomials which vanish on $B$. Therefore $J \subseteq I(B)$, and hence $V(I(B)) \subseteq V(J) = C$.

So the closure of $B$, which is the intersection of all closed sets containing $B$, is $V(I(B))$.

The Zariski closure of $B$ is $V(I(B)) = \mathbb{A}^n$, so $B$ is dense.

Comment: Why is that the closure? I'm having a hard time understanding that. Sorry if I'm being dense.

Comment: @user264885 The closure of $B$ is the smallest closed set containing it. Closed sets are of the form $V(I)$ for some ideal $I$. To find the smallest closed set containing $B$, we want the largest ideal $I$ such that all functions in $I$ vanish on $B$, which is by definition $I(B)$